# Carry excel cell format (bold, underline, italic) into React when pasting copied cells from Microsoft Excel

Tags: reactjs, excel, clipboard

I need to implement a feature: when a user copies cells from Microsoft Excel and pastes them into React table it needs to carry their styling too (like being **bold**, *italicized* or underlined).

I used Clipboard API to get data and I succeeded in getting data in text/plain or text/html.

```
const handlePaste = async (event: any) => {
    const clipboardContents = await navigator.clipboard.read();
    
    var textHtmlBlob : any;
    
    for (const item of clipboardContents) 
    { 
        textHtmlBlob = await item.getType("text/html");
    }

    console.log(await textHtmlBlob.text());
}
```

This way, I got the HTML table. I see it has classes like `"xl65"`, `"xl66"`, `"xl67"`.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="64" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:48pt">
  <tbody>
    <tr height="19" style="height:14.5pt">
      <td height="19" class="xl65" align="right" width="64" style="height:14.5pt;width:48pt">1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I investigated that if I use one of bold / underline / italicized cell, the cell will have only one class `"xl65"`, so I cannot distinguish how the cell was styled in Excel.

But if I use all three of them, I noticed, that `"xl65"` describes italicized cell, `"xl66"` describes underlined cell and `"xl67"` describes bold cell.

So, my question is how can I distinguish those class, so I could then apply CSS styles to make them look like they meant to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, you can use `event.clipboardData?.getData("text/html");` to get the HTML in text, and inside of it you'll have the `<style> </style>` section inside of `<head> </head>` element and there you can find all of the styles, including style definitions for classes `xl65` and others.

```js
const handlePaste = async (event: ClipboardEvent) => {
    event.clipboardData?.getData("text/html");
}
```